# Answer to sample size calculation is n1 = 2 + n2 = 2, can that be correct?

Tags: sample-size

I have computed a (online) sample size calculation for mean difference between two groups.
The calculation was done with the following data from literature:

[image]

The website used for the sample size calculation is: Sample Size Calculator (clincalc.com). This gave the following calculation with the data provided by literature
[image: calculation]
**The results of the calculation was n1 = 2, n2 = 2. Total sample size needed = 4. Im wondering if this can be correct? What should I do different?**

Our own dataset consists of only two variables: a) retention measured in Newton for conventional dentures and b) retention measured in Newton for digital dentures. With these variables we would like to conduct a t-test to test if there are significant differences in retention between the two types of dentures.
A pilot was conducted with four observations in total, maybe that helps (?)

[image]

The purpose of this study is for educational purposes.
If there is information missing, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds unlikely. What is the actual analysis model ? Also please tell us about all the variables in the model, and what assumptions you have made in the power/sample size calculation.  A summary of your dataset could be useful too. You can edit the question rather than replying to this comment.

Comment: Power should _never_ be computed based on observed differences.  Power is based on the difference you would be embarrassed to miss.

Comment: It is not going to take much to show Group II has a higher mean than Group I.  But I suspect the interesting question is the absolute or relative change "since insertion" and whether that differs between the two groups

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I've edited the question and provided some more information :)

Answer (score 1):

Given this huge difference in means relative to the standard deviations, that does seem possible.

I couldn't find an R power calculator for a t-test with unequal variances, but I ran a program with the smaller of the two SDs:

```
power.t.test(n = NULL, delta = 15.99-8.77, sd = 1.61, sig.level = 0.05,
             power = .8,
             type = "two.sample",
             alternative = "two.sided",
             strict = FALSE)
```

and got a required N of 2.24 per group.  With your larger SD I got a required sample of 3.89 per group.

But, if your data is similar to what you posted (i.e. three time points) then I doubt that this is the analysis you want to run.