# Answer to sample size calculation is n1 = 2 + n2 = 2, can that be correct? #2

Tags: sample-size

I have computed a (online) sample size calculation for mean difference between two groups.
The calculation was done with the following data from literature:

[image]

The website used for the sample size calculation is: Sample Size Calculator (https://clincalc.com/stats/samplesize.aspx). This gave the following calculation with the data provided by literature:
[image: calculation]
**The results of the calculation was n1 = 2, n2 = 2. Total sample size needed = 4. Im wondering if this can be correct? What should I do different?**

Our own dataset consists of only two variables: a) retention measured in Newton for conventional dentures and b) retention measured in Newton for digital dentures. With these variables we would like to conduct a t-test to test if there are significant differences in retention between the two types of dentures.
A pilot was conducted with four observations in total, maybe that helps (?)

[image]

The purpose of this study is for educational purposes.
If there is information missing, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

This post is a repost, the original question can be found here:  [Answer to sample size calculation is n1 = 2 + n2 = 2, can that be correct?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631689/answer-to-sample-size-calculation-is-n1-2-n2-2-can-that-be-correct?noredirect=1#comment1179445_631689)

Comment: You've already posted this question and received an answer, please don't duplicate your own questions.

Comment: I have mentioned that it's a repost :) I don't see an answer to my question myself?  And I didn't get new replies/answers after I edited my post with requested information, thats why I choose to post the question again

Comment: The answer is still in your previous question; yes, your calculation is roughly correct under your given assumptions, and no, this is possibly not the information you need/analysis you want to use. But just running a t-test on your pilot data gives $P=0.0283$ under the null of both means being equal (obviously under the applicable assumptions), for non-parametric this is too small to produce any weight of evidence against any null. The original study seemed to contain repeated measures which makes other models more appropriate.